# Error in building meteor app

Tags: meteor, deployment, meteor-up, meteor-packages, meteor-clt

When I try to deploy my app (with [meteor-up](https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up) `mup deploy` command) I got this error on build step then I test and found that same error also return when use `meteor build` command:

```
Building Started: /media/userName/Projects/Projects/appName

/home/userName/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.12dq88w++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:245
                        throw(ex);
                              ^
TypeError: Cannot call method 'split' of undefined
  at Object.parse (/home/userName/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.12dq88w++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/utils/parse-stack.js:23:26)
  at Object.exception (/home/userName/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.12dq88w++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/utils/buildmessage.js:480:29)
  at /home/userName/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.12dq88w++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/isobuild/bundler.js:871:22
  at /home/userName/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.12dq88w++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/utils/buildmessage.js:352:18
  at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (/home/userName/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.12dq88w++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/utils/fiber-helpers.js:116:14)
  at /home/userName/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.12dq88w++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/utils/buildmessage.js:345:34
  at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (/home/userName/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.12dq88w++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/utils/fiber-helpers.js:116:14)
  at /home/userName/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.12dq88w++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/utils/buildmessage.js:343:23
  at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (/home/userName/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.12dq88w++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/utils/fiber-helpers.js:116:14)
  at Object.enterJob (/home/userName/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.12dq88w++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/utils/buildmessage.js:317:26)
  at ClientTarget.minifyJs (/home/userName/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.12dq88w++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/isobuild/bundler.js:866:18)
  at /home/userName/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.12dq88w++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/isobuild/bundler.js:530:17
  at /home/userName/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.12dq88w++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/utils/buildmessage.js:352:18
  at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (/home/userName/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.12dq88w++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/utils/fiber-helpers.js:116:14)
  at /home/userName/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.12dq88w++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/utils/buildmessage.js:345:34
  at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (/home/userName/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.12dq88w++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/utils/fiber-helpers.js:116:14)
  at /home/userName/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.12dq88w++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/utils/buildmessage.js:343:23
  at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (/home/userName/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.12dq88w++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/utils/fiber-helpers.js:116:14)
  at Object.enterJob (/home/userName/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.12dq88w++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/utils/buildmessage.js:317:26)
  at ClientTarget.make (/home/userName/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.12dq88w++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/isobuild/bundler.js:492:18)
  at /home/userName/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.12dq88w++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/isobuild/bundler.js:2083:14
  at /home/userName/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.12dq88w++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/isobuild/bundler.js:2169:20
  at Array.forEach (native)
  at Function._.each._.forEach (/home/userName/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.12dq88w++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
  at /home/userName/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.12dq88w++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/isobuild/bundler.js:2168:7
  at /home/userName/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.12dq88w++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/utils/buildmessage.js:264:13
  at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (/home/userName/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.12dq88w++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/utils/fiber-helpers.js:116:14)
  at /home/userName/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.12dq88w++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/utils/buildmessage.js:257:29
  at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (/home/userName/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.12dq88w++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/utils/fiber-helpers.js:116:14)
  at /home/userName/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.12dq88w++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/utils/buildmessage.js:255:18
  at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (/home/userName/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.12dq88w++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/utils/fiber-helpers.js:116:14)
  at /home/userName/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.12dq88w++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/utils/buildmessage.js:246:23
  at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (/home/userName/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.12dq88w++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/utils/fiber-helpers.js:116:14)
  at Object.capture (/home/userName/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.12dq88w++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/utils/buildmessage.js:245:19)
  at Object.exports.bundle (/home/userName/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.12dq88w++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/isobuild/bundler.js:2070:31)
  at buildCommand (/home/userName/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.12dq88w++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/cli/commands.js:834:30)
  at Command.main.registerCommand._.extend.name [as func] (/home/userName/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.12dq88w++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/cli/commands.js:728:10)
  at /home/userName/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.12dq88w++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/cli/main.js:1227:23


=> Build Error. Check the logs printed above.
```

And this is my `meteor build --verbose` output:

```
meteor build --verbose "/media/userName/Projects/Projects/appName/test_build/"
Local package version is up-to-date: accounts-base@1.2.2
Local package version is up-to-date: accounts-password@1.1.4
Local package version is up-to-date: alanning:roles@1.2.14
Local package version is up-to-date: aldeed:autoform@5.8.1
Local package version is up-to-date: aldeed:collection2@2.8.0
Local package version is up-to-date: aldeed:collection2-core@1.0.0
Local package version is up-to-date: aldeed:schema-deny@1.0.1
Local package version is up-to-date: aldeed:schema-index@1.0.1
Local package version is up-to-date: aldeed:simple-schema@1.5.3
Local package version is up-to-date: anti:i18n@0.4.3
Local package version is up-to-date: autoupdate@1.2.4
Local package version is up-to-date: babel-compiler@5.8.24_1
Local package version is up-to-date: babel-runtime@0.1.4
Local package version is up-to-date: base64@1.0.4
Local package version is up-to-date: binary-heap@1.0.4
Local package version is up-to-date: blaze@2.1.3
Local package version is up-to-date: blaze-html-templates@1.0.1
Local package version is up-to-date: blaze-tools@1.0.4
Local package version is up-to-date: boilerplate-generator@1.0.4
Local package version is up-to-date: caching-compiler@1.0.0
Local package version is up-to-date: caching-html-compiler@1.0.2
Local package version is up-to-date: callback-hook@1.0.4
Local package version is up-to-date: check@1.1.0
Local package version is up-to-date: coffeescript@1.0.11
Local package version is up-to-date: dburles:collection-helpers@1.0.4
Local package version is up-to-date: dburles:mongo-collection-instances@0.3.4
Local package version is up-to-date: ddp@1.2.2
Local package version is up-to-date: ddp-client@1.2.1
Local package version is up-to-date: ddp-common@1.2.2
Local package version is up-to-date: ddp-rate-limiter@1.0.0
Local package version is up-to-date: ddp-server@1.2.2
Local package version is up-to-date: deps@1.0.9
Local package version is up-to-date: diff-sequence@1.0.1
Local package version is up-to-date: easy:search@2.0.6
Local package version is up-to-date: easysearch:components@2.0.6
Local package version is up-to-date: easysearch:core@2.0.5
Local package version is up-to-date: ecmascript@0.1.6
Local package version is up-to-date: ecmascript-runtime@0.2.6
Local package version is up-to-date: ejson@1.0.7
Local package version is up-to-date: email@1.0.8
Local package version is up-to-date: fastclick@1.0.7
Local package version is up-to-date: gadicohen:robots-txt@0.0.10
Local package version is up-to-date: gadicohen:sitemaps@0.0.23
Local package version is up-to-date: geojson-utils@1.0.4
Local package version is up-to-date: hot-code-push@1.0.0
Local package version is up-to-date: html-tools@1.0.5
Local package version is up-to-date: htmljs@1.0.5
Local package version is up-to-date: http@1.1.1
Local package version is up-to-date: ian:accounts-ui-bootstrap-3@1.2.84
Local package version is up-to-date: id-map@1.0.4
Local package version is up-to-date: insecure@1.0.4
Local package version is up-to-date: iron:controller@1.0.12
Local package version is up-to-date: iron:core@1.0.11
Local package version is up-to-date: iron:dynamic-template@1.0.12
Local package version is up-to-date: iron:layout@1.0.12
Local package version is up-to-date: iron:location@1.0.11
Local package version is up-to-date: iron:middleware-stack@1.0.11
Local package version is up-to-date: iron:router@1.0.12
Local package version is up-to-date: iron:url@1.0.11
Local package version is up-to-date: jquery@1.11.4
Local package version is up-to-date: lai:collection-extensions@0.1.4
Local package version is up-to-date: launch-screen@1.0.4
Local package version is up-to-date: livedata@1.0.15
Local package version is up-to-date: localstorage@1.0.5
Local package version is up-to-date: logging@1.0.8
Local package version is up-to-date: matb33:collection-hooks@0.8.1
Local package version is up-to-date: matteodem:easy-search@2.0.0
Local package version is up-to-date: maximum:package-base@1.1.2
Local package version is up-to-date: maximum:reactive-cursors@0.2.0
Local package version is up-to-date: maximum:server-transform@0.4.1
Local package version is up-to-date: mdg:validation-error@0.2.0
Local package version is up-to-date: meteor@1.1.10
Local package version is up-to-date: meteor-base@1.0.1
Local package version is up-to-date: meteorhacks:async@1.0.0
Local package version is up-to-date: meteorhacks:npm@1.5.0
Local package version is up-to-date: minifiers@1.1.7
Local package version is up-to-date: minimongo@1.0.10
Local package version is up-to-date: mobile-experience@1.0.1
Local package version is up-to-date: mobile-status-bar@1.0.6
Local package version is up-to-date: momentjs:moment@2.10.6
Local package version is up-to-date: mongo@1.1.3
Local package version is up-to-date: mongo-id@1.0.1
Local package version is up-to-date: npm-bcrypt@0.7.8_2
Local package version is up-to-date: npm-mongo@1.4.39_1
Local package version is up-to-date: observe-sequence@1.0.7
Local package version is up-to-date: ordered-dict@1.0.4
Local package version is up-to-date: peerlibrary:assert@0.2.5
Local package version is up-to-date: peerlibrary:base-component@0.14.0
Local package version is up-to-date: peerlibrary:blaze-components@0.15.1
Local package version is up-to-date: peerlibrary:computed-field@0.3.1
Local package version is up-to-date: peerlibrary:fiber-utils@0.5.1
Local package version is up-to-date: peerlibrary:reactive-field@0.1.0
Local package version is up-to-date: peerlibrary:server-autorun@0.5.1
Local package version is up-to-date: promise@0.5.1
Local package version is up-to-date: raix:eventemitter@0.1.3
Local package version is up-to-date: random@1.0.5
Local package version is up-to-date: rate-limit@1.0.0
Local package version is up-to-date: reactive-dict@1.1.3
Local package version is up-to-date: reactive-var@1.0.6
Local package version is up-to-date: reload@1.1.4
Local package version is up-to-date: retry@1.0.4
Local package version is up-to-date: routepolicy@1.0.6
Local package version is up-to-date: sacha:spin@2.3.1
Local package version is up-to-date: service-configuration@1.0.5
Local package version is up-to-date: session@1.1.1
Local package version is up-to-date: sha@1.0.4
Local package version is up-to-date: spacebars@1.0.7
Local package version is up-to-date: spacebars-compiler@1.0.7
Local package version is up-to-date: srp@1.0.4
Local package version is up-to-date: standard-minifiers@1.0.2
Local package version is up-to-date: stylus@2.511.1
Local package version is up-to-date: templating@1.1.5
Local package version is up-to-date: templating-tools@1.0.0
Local package version is up-to-date: tracker@1.0.9
Local package version is up-to-date: twbs:bootstrap@3.3.6
Local package version is up-to-date: ui@1.0.8 
Local package version is up-to-date: underscore@1.0.4
Local package version is up-to-date: url@1.0.5
Local package version is up-to-date: webapp@1.2.3
Local package version is up-to-date: webapp-hashing@1.0.5
Doing HTTP request:  POST                     
https://www.meteor.com/oauth2/authorize?state=ea01b021a4xyz90917e2d845c0b07b&response_type=code&client_id=Ldpxyz7xyzkDJ2&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Factivity.meteor.com%2F_oauth%2Fmeteor-developer%3Fclose

/home/userName/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.12dq88w++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:245
                        throw(ex);
                              ^
TypeError: Cannot call method 'split' of undefined
  at Object.parse (/home/userName/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.12dq88w++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/utils/parse-stack.js:23:26)
  at Object.exception (/home/userName/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.12dq88w++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/utils/buildmessage.js:480:29)
  at /home/userName/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.12dq88w++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/isobuild/bundler.js:871:22
  at /home/userName/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.12dq88w++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/utils/buildmessage.js:352:18
  at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (/home/userName/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.12dq88w++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/utils/fiber-helpers.js:116:14)
  at /home/userName/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.12dq88w++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/utils/buildmessage.js:345:34
  at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (/home/userName/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.12dq88w++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/utils/fiber-helpers.js:116:14)
  at /home/userName/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.12dq88w++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/utils/buildmessage.js:343:23
  at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (/home/userName/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.12dq88w++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/utils/fiber-helpers.js:116:14)
  at Object.enterJob (/home/userName/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.12dq88w++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/utils/buildmessage.js:317:26)
  at ClientTarget.minifyJs (/home/userName/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.12dq88w++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/isobuild/bundler.js:866:18)
  at /home/userName/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.12dq88w++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/isobuild/bundler.js:530:17
  at /home/userName/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.12dq88w++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/utils/buildmessage.js:352:18
  at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (/home/userName/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.12dq88w++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/utils/fiber-helpers.js:116:14)
  at /home/userName/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.12dq88w++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/utils/buildmessage.js:345:34
  at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (/home/userName/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.12dq88w++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/utils/fiber-helpers.js:116:14)
  at /home/userName/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.12dq88w++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/utils/buildmessage.js:343:23
  at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (/home/userName/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.12dq88w++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/utils/fiber-helpers.js:116:14)
  at Object.enterJob (/home/userName/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.12dq88w++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/utils/buildmessage.js:317:26)
  at ClientTarget.make (/home/userName/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.12dq88w++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/isobuild/bundler.js:492:18)
  at /home/userName/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.12dq88w++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/isobuild/bundler.js:2083:14
  at /home/userName/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.12dq88w++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/isobuild/bundler.js:2169:20
  at Array.forEach (native)
  at Function._.each._.forEach (/home/userName/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.12dq88w++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
  at /home/userName/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.12dq88w++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/isobuild/bundler.js:2168:7
  at /home/userName/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.12dq88w++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/utils/buildmessage.js:264:13
  at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (/home/userName/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.12dq88w++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/utils/fiber-helpers.js:116:14)
  at /home/userName/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.12dq88w++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/utils/buildmessage.js:257:29
  at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (/home/userName/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.12dq88w++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/utils/fiber-helpers.js:116:14)
  at /home/userName/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.12dq88w++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/utils/buildmessage.js:255:18
  at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (/home/userName/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.12dq88w++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/utils/fiber-helpers.js:116:14)
  at /home/userName/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.12dq88w++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/utils/buildmessage.js:246:23
  at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (/home/userName/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.12dq88w++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/utils/fiber-helpers.js:116:14)
  at Object.capture (/home/userName/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.12dq88w++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/utils/buildmessage.js:245:19)
  at Object.exports.bundle (/home/userName/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.12dq88w++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/isobuild/bundler.js:2070:31)
  at buildCommand (/home/userName/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.12dq88w++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/cli/commands.js:834:30)
  at Command.main.registerCommand._.extend.name [as func] (/home/userName/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.12dq88w++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/cli/commands.js:728:10)
  at /home/userName/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.12dq88w++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/cli/main.js:1227:23
```

My app run correctly now without any error but has error on build. I deploy this project some days ago without any problem. But after `meteor update` and add [maximum:server-transform](https://atmospherejs.com/maximum/server-transform) package deploy error appear. I also try to remove `maximum:server-transform` package and test again but it isn't fix.

This is my project `meteor list` output if useful:

```
accounts-password            1.1.4  Password support for accounts
alanning:roles               1.2.14  Authorization package for Meteor
aldeed:autoform              5.8.1  Easily create forms with automatic insert and update, and automatic reactive validation.
aldeed:collection2           2.8.0  Automatic validation of insert and update operations on the client and server.
aldeed:simple-schema         1.5.3  A simple schema validation object with reactivity. Used by collection2 and autoform.
blaze-html-templates         1.0.1  Compile HTML templates into reactive UI with Meteor Blaze
check                        1.1.0  Check whether a value matches a pattern
dburles:collection-helpers   1.0.4  Transform your collections with helpers that you define
ejson                        1.0.7  Extended and Extensible JSON library
gadicohen:sitemaps           0.0.23  functions to easily output valid sitemaps
ian:accounts-ui-bootstrap-3  1.2.84  Bootstrap-styled accounts-ui with multi-language support.
insecure                     1.0.4  (For prototyping only) Allow all database writes from the client
iron:router                  1.0.12  Routing specifically designed for Meteor
jquery                       1.11.4  Manipulate the DOM using CSS selectors
logging                      1.0.8  Logging facility.
matteodem:easy-search        2.0.0  Easy-to-use search with Blaze Components (+ Elastic Search support)
maximum:server-transform     0.4.1  Meteor package to transform documents on publish
meteor-base                  1.0.1  Packages that every Meteor app needs
meteorhacks:npm              1.5.0  Use npm modules with your Meteor App
mobile-experience            1.0.1  Packages for a great mobile user experience
mongo                        1.1.3  Adaptor for using MongoDB and Minimongo over DDP
npm-container                1.2.0+ Contains all your npm dependencies
random                       1.0.5  Random number generator and utilities
reactive-dict                1.1.3  Reactive dictionary
reload                       1.1.4  Reload the page while preserving application state.
sacha:spin                   2.3.1  Simple spinner package for Meteor
session                      1.1.1  Session variable
spacebars                    1.0.7  Handlebars-like template language for Meteor
standard-minifiers           1.0.2  Standard minifiers used with Meteor apps by default.
tracker                      1.0.9  Dependency tracker to allow reactive callbacks
twbs:bootstrap               3.3.6  The most popular front-end framework for developing responsive, mobile first projects on the web.


+ These packages are built locally from source.
```

I also try `DEBUG=* mup deploy` for verbose mode but it isn't new detail about error.

I also try build project after `meteor reset` but it isn't work.

Please help me to troubleshoot this error if it's possible. How to find that where is the error?? How to trace build process??
How to find that in which file `TypeError: Cannot call method 'split' of undefined` happened??